# SQL-Server. Select data from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I'm using SQL-server. I have 2 tables: `Items (Id, OwnerId, ItemName)` and `Owners (Id, OwnerName)`

It should select something like (connect data from 2 tables):

`OwnerName | Items.Id | ItemName`

I've tried:

```
SELECT OwnerName, Items.Id, ItemName
FROM Items, Owners
```

But It not working, have you ideas?

Comment: You probably need third table containing ids of both tables at least as relationship seem many-to- many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) tables.

```
SELECT o.OwnerName, i.Id, i.ItemName
FROM Items AS i
JOIN Owners AS o 
ON o.Id = i.OwnerId
```

Comment: Or it could be: on o.Id = I.Id depending on your table structure

Comment: I think It's good. `Id` from `Owners` table and `OwnerId` from `Items` table. Look at tables structure in question.